# How convert an int64 to minutes ? Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to transform this column (format int64) to a minutes format to do calculation

```
Duration(min)
10
30
5
15
5
```

I tried this:

```
df['Duration(min)'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Duration(min)'], format='%H%M')
```

But I have **ValueError:** time data '5' does not match format '%H%M' (match)

Comment: These values are very small to create datetime. There should be at least 2 digits

Comment: Can you detail your use case a little more?  Why do you need a date format?

Comment: It's  a duration of an intervention in a case of maintenance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [**`pd.to_timedelta`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) here.

```
pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration(min)'], unit='min')

0   0 days 00:10:00
1   0 days 00:30:00
2   0 days 00:05:00
3   0 days 00:15:00
4   0 days 00:05:00
Name: Duration(min), dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

> `unit` -> `‘m’ / ‘minute’ / ‘min’ / ‘minutes’ / ‘T’` all are shorthand for *minutes*.

Answer (score 3):

Using [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) -

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Duration(min), unit='m').dt.strftime('%H:%M')
```

Output-

```
0    00:10
1    00:30
2    00:05
3    00:15
4    00:05
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Why %H%M when all you have is minutes?  Try format='%M'.